# Schengen Business visa without a business invitation letter

Tags: schengen, business-travel

To apply for a Schengen business visa, you need a letter from the company in the Member state inviting you. My company is based in the UK, owns properties in Schengen countries, and I have to inspect their condition.

What letter do I get?

Comment: Where do you see the requirement that the company must be in the member state?

Answer (score 1):

For a Schengen Business visa you will need a cover letter explaining, in detail, the purpose of the visit. It is like almost anyother company letter, on an official letter head filled in with all of the business details. I am assuming that the letterhead will contain the address/phone/email/fax etc of the company.

The letter format can be something like this:

> **[Letterhead of Company]**
>
> **To**: Consulate General of [the country of travel]
>
> **[Date]**
>
> Dear Consul General:
>
> Through this letter, I want to confirm that Mr./Mrs. *[Name and last
>   name]* is an employee at our firm *[company name]*, as *[job
>   title/position]*. Mr./Mrs. *[Name]* has been working with our company
>   for the last *[number of years]* and will be travelling to *[name of
>   city]*, *[country]* starting from *[date of entry]* until *[date of
>   exit]* for a total of *[number of days]* to attend to the following
>   work-related activities:
>
> **Write in as much detail as possible about the business that will be conducted abroad. This would be a date-by-date break down of your business plan**
>
> While *[name of employee]* is visiting your country, it is important
>   to also visit *[name of visiting company and contact details]*.
>
> Mr./Mrs. *[Name]* will be staying at *[hotel name, address, phone
>   number]*. I kindly ask for the *[visa type]* to be issued to Mr./Mrs.
>   *[Name and last name]* at your earliest convenience.
>
> Applicant Details:
>
> *[name of employee]*
>
> *[date of birth]*
>
> *[address]*
>
> *[passport number]*
>
> Please, do not hesitate to contact me should you have any further
>   inquiries. Thank you for your assistance.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> *[Supervisor signature]*
>
> *[Name and last name]*
>
> *[Title]*
>
> *[Email*
>
> *[Phone number]*
>
> *[company website]*

Of course you can make adjustments to this as needed for your business purpose/visit. Another document that may be required to complement this letter would be your "Company brief/profile". It may be a letter explaining what your company profile is what your company does for busine